# Use of Array in a Struct in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, struct

I have the following struct where I use string, Int, and Bool. I fill these variable when I query my products from Firestore. Now I do not know how to treat an array here in my struct:

```
struct Product {
    var price: Int
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool
    //var categories: how do I call out the array here?
init(
        price: Int,
        name: String,
        isActive: Bool,
        //categories: how do I call out the array here?
        ){
        self.price = price
        self.name = name
        self.isActive = isActive
        //self.categories: how do I call out the array here?
    }

    init(data: [String: Any]){
        price = data[DatabaseRef.price] as? Int ?? 0
        name = data[DatabaseRef.name] as? String ?? ""
        isActive = data[DatabaseRef.isActive] as? Bool ?? false
        //categories: how do I call out the array here?
    }

static func modelToData(product: Product) -> [String: Any] {

        let data : [String: Any] = [
            DatabaseRef.price : product.price,
            DatabaseRef.name : product.name,
            DatabaseRef.isActive : product.isActive,
           //categories: how do I call out the array here?
       ]
        return data
    }
}
```

When I query my categories from my database; it would look like this:

```
categories = ["Fruits", "Vegetables", "Frozen"]
```

Not sure how I can call the categories out in each part of the struct I mentioned up here. Newbie alert!

Comment: Just declare a property of type `[String]`

Comment: Makes sense; how about for this line? `category = data[DatabaseRef.category] as? [String] ?? [ ]` is that how you declare it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare an array like this.

var categories: [String] = []